# RESTKit: Reusing objectManager to make subsequent `POST`

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using the following code to POST:

```
[self.objectManager postObject:invitation path:kPath parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            }];
```

And it `POST`s fine the first time; however, when I try subsequent `POST`s, I get the following error:

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[RKObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:], /Users/User/Documents...../Code/Network/RKObjectManager.m:766
2014-05-15 22:07:43.103 App[68071:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot add request descriptor: An existing descriptor is already registered for the class 'Entity' and HTTP method'*'.'
```

How do I detect if a request/response `descriptor` has been added already?  What's the proper practice for reusing `descriptor`'s?  Is there anything else I need to NULL out or not do to avoid crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the POST, the problem is that you are running your mapping configuration repeatedly (each time you want to POST).

The mappings need to be unique (deterministic) so running multiple times is not permitted. You could delete them each time, but that's wasteful, so really you should just load them once when you create the object manager and then not do it again. In this way you get optimum reuse.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to check if the object already has a mapping?

Comment: You shouldn't need to - it should be correct by design if you configure the mappings at launch time and then don't change them

Comment: I don't always post with same objects. Meaning I have different entities. So depending upon what entity I need to post with, I need to change the mapping. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You post different kinds of object to the same endpoint? That isn't a very good rest web service

Comment: It's the same url, but different mapping for POST and PUT.

Comment: That's the purpose of the method parameter on the response descriptor (bump date to a newer version of RestKit if you don't have that parameter).

Comment: Hey, I really struggled with this today. I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718498/restkit-two-urls-post-put-delete   Thanks!